# VS2010 Unit Tests - thrown exceptions are blank

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2010

Hopefully a nice n simple one for you

Running some tests in VS2010's testing framework.
When an exception is thrown somewhere inside it, the results screen shows nothing of the details.

Simplest example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DoTest()
{
    int y = 10 - 10;
    int x = 10 / y;
}
```

Test method MyProj.DoTest threw exception: 
...

You can't see it here, but before the '...' there is some sort of special hidden character (displays as a square).
How can I view the details, and ideally, the stacktrace.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but in the meantime, you should be able to see the exception in the debugger.

Comment: The test fails and exits as soon as the exception is thrown. So there is no way to see it without wrapping it in a try/catch and examining the caught exception.
Fine in this case, but not when I dont know where the exception is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't have to add try/catch blocks. If you simply click Debug instead of Run:

[image]

it will automatically break there and show you the type of exception:
[image]

You must also make sure to go to Debug -> Exceptions (Ctrl+Alt+E) and go to Common Language Runtime Exceptions->System->ystem.DivideByZero exception is either Thrown, or User-andled. If neither of those are checked, nothing will be shown as you debug, and you will get what you described. This, of course, is true for all exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I would trace through the test code using the debugger until you find the line where the exception is being thrown. That will help you narrow it down.

Comment: That's what I am doing now.
Is there no other way? seems pretty poor on MS's part. NUnit would always give you a full stack trace on a failed test.
And now, even when I find the line, I can't see why it is failing, I have to edit the code to put a try/catch around the failing line to be able to see anything of what is causing it to fail.

Answer (score -1):

You just double click on the failed test in the Test Results window or Right Click> View Test Results Details